# How to simplify 2 conditions that rely on one another but lead to the same result?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, idioms, simplification

I have a function that accepts an integer year, but I also want the user to be able to pass in the string `'ALL'` and still be able to get something back.

I have this ugly piece of code right now:

```
if type(year) != str or (type(year) == str and year.upper() != 'ALL'):
    total_results = self.filterResultsByYear(total_results, year, year2)
```

Results are filtered by default to the current year, and can be filtered by other years, but if the user wants to not filter, they have to pass in 'all' for the year.

The reason I wrote the above abomination is if I just have `if year.upper() != 'ALL'` I get a `TypeError` if I pass in an integer. If I put `if type(year) != str and year.upper() != 'ALL'` I still get the same error. The above code looks really ugly and I wanted to make it more pythonic. What tools do I have to do this?

Comment: What is the expected behavior when `year` is a string but not "all"?

Comment: Do you always expect valid input? If not I'd say just check if it's a valid year or don't apply the filter at all.

Comment: @DYZ I want to throw an error/alert the user that the input was invalid. Basically I want the filter to be applied by default and if the user supplies an int, but if the user supplied a string and that string happens to be `'all'`, then I want to ignore the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what `total_results` and `year2` are and how you'd like to handle them:

```
try:
    year = int(year)
    total_results = self.filterResultsByYear(total_results, year, year2)
except ValueError:
    if not isinstance(year, (str, unicode)):
        raise  # Not string, unicode or coercible to an integer.
    if year.lower() == 'all':
        # Your logic here.
    else:
        # String but not 'all'.  Exception handling.
```

Bye the way, to check for class equivalency one uses `isinstance(object, class)` or `isinstance(object, (class 1, class 2, ...))`.

Comment: The way I wanted the code flow to work is for the filter to be applied unless the year is equal to `'all'` then it is ignored. By default the filter is applied.